# getting total of subset of data frames

Tags: r

I have dynamic columns of data frame like below not i am trying to create a subtotal of numeric values in columns. but getting error like below . class of columns is character

objective is create a row "Total" with sum of columns

[image]

```
tot <- mapply(sum,as.numeric(tab1[-1,-1]))

Error in mapply(sum, as.numeric(tab1[-1, -1])) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: try `lapply(as.data.frame(tab1[-1,-1]), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column can have data of only one type so if you have values like 'CC', 'CC1' in your data it means that the columns are of type character. After removing 1st row and 1st column you need to change the type of columns to numeric and calculate their sum. Changing type of columns can be done with `type.convert`.

```
total <- colSums(type.convert(tab1[-1,-1]))
total
#  A   B   C 
#143 151 135
```

If you want to add this as a new row in the dataframe :

```
tab2 <- rbind(tab1, data.frame(T = 'Total', t(total)))
tab2

#      T   A   B   C
#1    T1  CC CC1 CC2
#2    T2  39  29  36
#3    T3  52  88  41
#4    T4  52  34  58
#5 Total 143 151 135
```

**data**

Please provide data in a reproducible format and not as pictures.

```
tab1 <- data.frame(T = paste0('T', 1:4), A = c('CC', 39, 52, 52), 
                   B = c('CC1', 29, 88, 34), C = c('CC2', 36, 41, 58))
```

Comment: t1 <- data.frame(T = paste0('T', 1:4), A = c('CC', 39, 52, 52), 
                   B = c('CC1', 29, 88, 34), C = c('CC2', 36, 41, 58))

total1 <- colSums(type.convert(t1[-1,-1]))
total1
t2 <- rbind(t1, data.frame(T = 'Total', t(total)))
t2
getting this error              Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: data is same thanks tab1 <- data.frame(T = paste0('T', 1:4), A = c('CC', 39, 52, 52), 
                   B = c('CC1', 29, 88, 34), C = c('CC2', 36, 41, 58))

Comment: It works for me as shown in the answer if I use the data from my post. If you are on R < 4.0.0 use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` call. `tab1 <- data.frame(T = paste0('T', 1:4), A = c('CC', 39, 52, 52), B = c('CC1', 29, 88, 34), C = c('CC2', 36, 41, 58), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and `tab2 <- rbind(tab1, data.frame(T = 'Total', t(total), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))`

Comment: tried this way too t1 <- data.frame(T = paste0('T', 1:4), A = c('CC', 39, 52, 52), 
                   B = c('CC1', 29, 88, 34), C = c('CC2', 36, 41, 58),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

total1 <- colSums(type.convert(t1[-1,-1]))
total1 
t2 <- rbind(t1,data.frame(T = 'Total', t(total),stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
t2    still the same error and version i am using is 4.0.3

Comment: Make sure you are using the right variable names. You are saving data in `total1` and then using `t(total)` in `rbind`, use `t(total1)`. If it still doesn't work restart R and try again.

Comment: total <- colSums(type.convert(t1[-1,-1]))
total1 <- cbind(T="total",t(total))
t2 <- rbind(t1,total1)
tried this way and now its working perfectly fine Thanks alot for your help

Comment: one more question, suppose sometimes that table can have one column only then how can i make this dynamic.....??  total <- colSums(type.convert(tab1[-1,-1]))

Comment: tab1 <- data.frame(T = paste0('T', 1:4), A = c('CC', 0, 0, 0))
like this then should i use across...??

Comment: Add `drop = FALSE`. `total <- colSums(type.convert(tab1[-1,-1, drop = FALSE]))`